# How do you figure out your current program deployed max size?

Tags: program, deploy

When you deploy a program to a cluster, the default size allocated is the binary size * 2. However you won't be using the entire space on the cluster. How do you figure out the space left available in the program data account based on the current deployed program?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hey you could get the account info from the executable data account and count the As at the end.

```
var programAccount =
            await Web3.Instance.WalletBase.ActiveRpcClient.GetAccountInfoAsync(
                "EnL1LHhEZ1jEDBbrwScGDsJLux4mos4rG5bthzDCwGDB", Commitment.Confirmed);

        int emptyBytes = 0;
        foreach (char dataByte in programAccount.Result.Value.Data[0])
        {
            if (dataByte == 65)
            {
                emptyBytes++;
            }
            else
            {
                emptyBytes = 0;
            }
        }
        Debug.Log(emptyBytes);
```